# Why does Console.ReadKey().Key.ToString get lower and uppercase Letter by pressing once?

Tags: c#, console.readkey

This snipet Outputs two Letters when i press one Key (r).

```
string key = string.Empty;
key = Console.ReadKey().Key.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(key);
Console.ReadKey();
// Output: rR
```

Why does it output lower 'r' and Upercase 'R'  when i only press once the lowercase 'r'?

Comment: Because it is reading and outputting the pressed key `r` and after that writing the uppercase version `R`. This is its defined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lower case `r` is what you have written from keyboard. You do not remove it form console by reading it. And the capital letter `R` is the character representation of the `Key` from `ConsoleKeyInfo` structure. If you want to read exactly what was written to console use `Console.Read()` or `Console.ReadLine()`.

Answer (score 1):

`Console.ReadKey` returns the `ConsoleKeyInfo` object which expose a property `Key` which is of `ConsoleKey` type. Where the `Key` is represented with `enum` value With upper case letter. See below.

[image]

Now in your case, you are first reading which is `r` using `Console.ReadKey()` and they you are outputting the code using `Console.WriteLine` which is printing Key value as `R`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Key`-property returns a value of the enum `ConsoleKey`.
The enum `ConsoleKey` has a equivalent for every non-modifier-key (Alt, Shift & Ctrl; see enum `ConsoleModifiers`).
Therefor, there are 2 possible signs that can be produced by pressing the key "R".

Another example to illustrate this is when you press `4` in your line of numbers above the keys. This is the `ConsoleKey` D4. It can be (see `key.KeyChar`) `4` or `$`. Also note the property `Modifiers` in the `ConsoleKeyInfo`-class that shows the pressed modifying key.

See the example below to illustrate it:

```
var key = Console.ReadKey();//press 4
Console.WriteLine("ConsoleKey: " + key.Key); // D4
Console.WriteLine("Char: " + key.KeyChar); // 4
Console.WriteLine("ConsoleModifier: " + key.Modifiers); // 0
            
key = Console.ReadKey(); //press shift + 4
Console.WriteLine("ConsoleKey: " + key.Key); // D4
Console.WriteLine("Char: " + key.KeyChar); // $
Console.WriteLine("ConsoleModifier: " + key.Modifiers); // Shift
```

I've taken some information from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx)

BTW: I only get "R" when pressing "R" or "r". I'm using C#6 with .Net 4.7. Perhaps you're using some newer or older version where it outputs all possible chars instead of the enum value itself on `.ToString()`, like it does @ me.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but thought this may be useful to add.

As others have noted, `Console.ReadKey()` does the job of both reading your inputted key and also writing it to screen (before your `Console.WriteLine()` takes effect).

If you just wanted to read the input and not write it, you can use the optional bool intercept argument of `Console.ReadKey()` to hide the user input, and then write it later:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey(true); // hiding input
Console.Write($"You pressed: {cki.Key}");

// press letter "a" (lower case)
// Output: You pressed: A
// i.e. no duplicated letter

Console.ReadLine();
```

[Link to MSDN section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=netframework-4.8#System_Console_ReadKey_System_Boolean_)

If you needed lowercase output, just needs a slight modification:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey(true); // hiding input
Console.Write($"You pressed: {cki.Key.ToString().ToLower()}");
// press letter "a" (lower case)    
// Output: You pressed: a

Console.ReadLine();
```